FTP connection via batch script
Using a batch script, I wanted to make a copies of files from a server to an FTP server and got username and password errors.
My batch file code is this:
@echo off
:: Define FTP variables
set "ftpServer=ftp-test.scs.group.wan"
set "ftpUser=*********"
set "ftpPassword=*******"
set "localFolderPath=D:\DOCS\EDI\outbound"
set "remoteFolderPath=/invoice/in/"

:: Create FTP script commands
(
    echo open %ftpServer%
    echo user %ftpUser% %ftpPassword%
    echo binary
    echo lcd "%localFolderPath%"
    echo cd "%remoteFolderPath%"
    echo mput *.*
    echo bye
) > ftpCommands.txt

:: Execute FTP script with verbose output for debugging
ftp -v -n -s:ftpCommands.txt

:: Check if FTP operation was successful
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
   echo ERROR: FTP upload failed.
   del ftpCommands.txt
   pause
   exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
)

:: Clean up temporary file
del ftpCommands.txt
@echo Files have been uploaded successfully!
pause

I cannot connect with username and password.

You got an error. Post the complete text of any error message you see, in your question. Try running the batch without @echo off and without the -v parameter to ftp so you can see what messages the server is sending.

Try echo user %ftpUser% and echo pass %ftpPassword%

I got this error:
ftp> open ftp-test.scs.group.wan
ftp> user s1-dmz-gip-skgreece
User cannot log in.
Login failed.
ftp> binary
ftp> lcd "D:\DOCS\EDI\outbound"
Local directory now D:\DOCS\EDI\outbound.
ftp> cd "/invoice/in/"
Please login with USER and PASS.
ftp> mput .
mput 146953.ivc? bye
mput 146954.ivc? mput 146955.ivc? mput 146956.ivc? mput ftpCommands.txt? mput OK? mput script 20241223.bat? mput script20241223B.bat? mput scripts? mput test.txt? ftp> quit
Files have been uploaded successfully!
Press any key to continue . . .

Do not post information in comments. Edit everything into your question.  + Try the -v as you have been suggested. + What research did you make based on the error you are getting? There are several questions on this error message already.  What debugging did you do? + As you have a problem with login, I guess that majority of the code in your question is irrelevant to the problem. Please reduce your code to [mcve].

I stumble over echo user %ftpUser% %ftpPassword%. Isn't that two inputs? As I read it, you try to connect with user "username password" and "binary" as password.

@Stephan That should be ok: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-user

@Martin, it seems you are correct. @George: There might be another pitfall: any poison chars in username or password?
